# split method not sperating special characters

Tags: java

I'm working a program that counts the accurrences of words in a text file. The program compiles and runs fine, but I'm tryting to use the split method to seperate special characters such as `.,;:!?(){}` from the words.

here is an output example

```
 6       eyes,
 3       eyes.
 2       eyes;
 1       eyes?
 1       eyrie
```

As you can see the split fuction is not working. I have tried debugging, but no luck so far. Can anythone point me out to the right direction or tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

    public class testingForLetters {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // open the file
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is the name of the text file? ");
    String fileName = console.nextLine();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));


    // count occurrences
    Map<String, Integer> wordCounts = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
    while (input.hasNext()) {

        input.next().split("[ \n\t\r.,;:!?(){}]" );
        String next = input.next().toLowerCase();


        if (next.startsWith("a") || next.startsWith("b") || next.startsWith("c") || next.startsWith("d") || next.startsWith("e") )  {

          if (!wordCounts.containsKey(next)) {
              wordCounts.put(next, 1);
          } else {
              wordCounts.put(next, wordCounts.get(next) + 1);
          }

        }
    }
    // get cutoff and report frequencies
    System.out.println("Total words = " + wordCounts.size());
    for (String word : wordCounts.keySet()) {
        int count = wordCounts.get(word);
        System.out.println(count + "\t" + word);

     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well if you include ".,;:" as a delimiter then those characters are effectively removed from the input.  They're treated as **delimiters** not input data.

Answer (score 3):

The `.split()` method returns an array of strings, and right now you aren't setting `input.next().split()` equal to anything.  You have to create an array and set it equal to `input.next().split()`, and then get the word(s) from the array.  You basically need to handle it exactly like you handled the `.toLowerCase()` part where you set `String next = input.next().toLowerCase()`.  Hope this helps.